# Can't remove node_modules from excluded folders in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Recently WebStorm marked `node_modules` as excluded and I can't remove it from excluded list. Furthermore in `Directories` menu, `node_modules` is not in `Excluded folders` (see picture below), although `node_modules` icon is red. When I try to remove `node_modules` from excluded, nothing happens.
[image]

Does anybody know how to remove `node_modules` from excluded folders?

Comment: Did you try right clicking on node_modules and unselecting Excluded?

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah, I recently updated WebStorm to 2016.2.2. Thank you!

Comment: Same issue here. Have searched everywhere for this new global setting. Almost seems like the node_modules exclude is hardcoded in the new version.