# Include certain node_modules

Tags: webstorm

Seems that in the latest WebStorm (2016.2.3?), node_modules is marked as an excluded directory by default. There are certain directories within node_modules that I want to include in my project files and searches. So I used to go to Preferences > Directories and exclude all of the modules I didn't need. However, I'm not able to "unexclude" the parent node_modules anymore. I have also tried unchecking the option in Preferences > Languages > JavaScript > Libraries without luck.

Same question with screenshot, if needed: [Can't remove node_modules from excluded folders in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024669/cant-remove-node-modules-from-excluded-folders-in-webstorm?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that when you have a `package.json` file, the `node_modules` is automatically excluded. Since you probably don't want to remove that, you could create an additional lib folder with symlinks to each module you want to include from `node_modules`.

*If you are on Windows, you can use the `mklink` command for this, in Linux/Mac the file manager might have a Make link option, or just use `ln -s node_modules/socket.io lib/` from the command line.*

You could also install the modules you need indexed into `subfolder/node_modules`, with subfolder having no package.json, and only the top-level node_modules folder will be marked as library.

Related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22909

Comment: Nice find, looks like it may be fixed in the next version. Another workaround from a comment in a linked issue:
(1) rename node_modules to something
(2) restart IDE
(3) rename something to node_modules

This only works if you're in the habit of leaving your IDE running. It will revert on the next restart