# Can't succeed in unexcluding node_modules in WebStorm Node React

Tags: webstorm, node-modules, local-node-modules

I can't un-exclude `node_modules` in WebStorm 2018.2.3.

When I click to uncheck excluded nothing happens. I tried restarting my IDE and my laptop but got the same result.

Is there a reason? I found this link (for an older version of WebStorm) but it doesn't work for me: [Can't remove node_modules from excluded folders in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024669/cant-remove-node-modules-from-excluded-folders-in-webstorm)

[image: Uncheck excluded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your answer. I manage to did it's not very proper way : I delete node_modules from my git repo then i push -f to my repo it works but your solution seems better. Unfortunately I've tried to unexclude (as I explained before) in Webstorm preferences but it has no effects. That's why I did that.

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm auto-excludes `node_modules` folder from the project for better performance, but it's excluded only partially: direct project dependencies listed in `package.json` are added to [JavaScript libraries](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/) for completion/navigation and thus indexed.
You can still un-exclude certain folders explicitly by choosing **Mark directory as | Not excluded** from folder right-click menu in the **Project** tree on the left. But note that un-excluding the node_modules folder would have negative performance impact.
See also [WEB-24765](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24765#focus=streamItem-27-2986788-0-0)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I manage to did it's not very proper way : I delete node_modules from my git repo then i push -f to my repo it works but your solution seems better. Unfortunately I've tried to unexclude (as I explained before) in Webstorm preferences but it has no effects. That's why I did that.